# Mysql Issue with Inserting to table with foreignKeys

Tags: mysql

I am pretty new to MySql.
I have a problem with insertion to a table with foriegnKeys to another table. Below mentioned is the syntax of the parent Table and child Table.

**=== Parent====**

```
 CREATE TABLE `userTable_temp` (
  `id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `contactNum` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `contactNum` (`contactNum`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**==== Child =====**

```
 CREATE TABLE `friendTable_temp` (
  `id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `friendId` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_test` (`userId`,`friendId`),
  KEY `friendId` (`friendId`),
  CONSTRAINT `friendTable_temp_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`friendId`) REFERENCES `userTable`   (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `friendTable_temp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `userTable` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**I am able to insert some records to friendTable_temp, but after 4th insertion, I always get the following Error**

```
 "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`contacts_db`.`friendTable_temp`, CONSTRAINT `friendTable_temp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `userTable` (`id`))"
```

When this issue happens I have the following data in UserTable_temp

mysql> select id, contactNum from userTable_temp;

+----+---------------+

| id | contactNum    |

+----+---------------+

|  1 | 123455677     |

|  2 | 56465465464   |

|  3 | 567576567     |

|  4 | 1231231231    |

|  5 | 35453453454   |

|  6 | 45645645645   |

+----+---------------+

6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

And the above error happens when I tried to do this

insert into friendTable_temp (userId,friendId) values (6,1);

Could you please help me on finding out what I doing wrong??

**Note:** 
insert into friendTable_temp (userId,friendId) values (5,1);

Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

Thanks

Comment: int(32) is not a valid declaration.

Comment: @Trinity Since when? The number in parentheses is just the display width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your Child table definition as Below.

```
CREATE TABLE `friendTable_temp` (
  `id` int(32) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `friendId` int(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `uc_test` (`userId`,`friendId`),
  KEY `friendId` (`friendId`),
  CONSTRAINT `friendTable_temp_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`friendId`) REFERENCES `userTable_temp`   (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `friendTable_temp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `userTable_temp` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Since I have tried adding just one record to the friendTable_temp, this is the current entries in friendTable_temp

+----+--------+----------+

| id | userId | friendId |

+----+--------+----------+

|  2 |      5 |        1 |

+----+--------+----------+

Comment: can you show output of "userTable" table. From error message it shows that you are violating friendTable_temp_ibfk_1 constraint. The question has output from usertable_temp. but the Foreginkey constraint is on usertable.

Comment: Its mentioned in the original question itself!!

Comment: original question has data from "userTable_temp". I want to know data from "usertable".

Comment: CONSTRAINT `friendTable_temp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `userTable` (`id`), here you are refering userTable.   Change Constraint to   CONSTRAINT `friendTable_temp_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`userId`) REFERENCES `userTable_Temp` (`id`)

Comment: Thanks!!! That comment just saved me  :)
userTable was some spurious table which was used for some other development and it was left hanging there.. I never realized that that userId was indeed a foreignKey to userTable rather than userTable_temp...
Many thanks for your valuable time!!!

Comment: I have just signed into stackoverflow with just not enuf reputations to vote up.. Sorry!!